# The meaning of "100%" in "a fast way that was 100%"

Tags: meaning-in-context, numbers

I'm trying to translate the following sentences ([source](http://www.watch-listen-read.com/english/Fool-Proof-Test-for-Primes-Numberphile-id-106405)):

> And finally they found a fast way that was 100%.
>   And if they're not it's composite. It's 100% this test.

but I do not understand that *100%*.

Comment: Can you give us more context?  Where did you find these sentences?

Comment: There's a "non-standard deletion" involved here. The context is mathematicians searching for a new way to establish quickly whether any given number is "prime" or not. The missing word is probably *And finally they found a fast way that was 100% **reliable*** (or similar, such as ***accurate***). Note that the entire text on that page is poor quality English. Don't think of it as a model to emulate.

Comment: @stangdon, I think **mstorkson** has inserted the source in my question text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree that the text is poor quality English. You are probably correct in saying not to think of it as a model to emulate but it is how native British English communicate when using informal spoken language. (I am not an expert and have no formal English qualifications)

Comment: @RedPython: I only glanced at it first time around. I now see it's a transcript of a *conversation*, which obviously makes a lot of difference. And while the transcription *may* be accurate in terms of the actual words spoken (I don't know), it contains plenty of additional errors in respect of the orthography, so I wouldn't recommend it even if you wanted to accurately reflect all the "mistakes" people frequently make in relaxed spoken contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an informal usage, so I wouldn't use it outside of casual conversation/communication.

> And finally they found a fast way that was 100%.

What this means, is that this new method they are discussing works every time, for every case (at least they are making the claim). It works "100% of the time", and they're just shorting that to "100%".

> 100%

Can be used inexactly in english slang to indicate something that is very good. For example if I said

> I'm feeling 100% today

It would mean I am feeling very good, as though I am capable of using "100%" of my abilities and faculties.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct!  In this case the phase is being spoken by Dr Grimes. - a professional mathematician famous for his _Numberphile_ video contributions, so I think it is safe to assume that when he says, "a fast way that was 100%" he is not using slang, rather the method works 100% of the time.